# Can an ASPX CascadingDropDown Extender use a Service Path that is not an ASMX? (WFC SVC or Data Service)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-ajax, wcf-data-services, svc

I have noticed that all the example in the internet uses Service Path of ASMX for a cascading dropdown list, is there a way to use more modern technology as it's service path? I was wondering if I could use DataServices for it?

Comment: I have tried to use a WCF service and it does not work. The service gets called but something is different between the serialization between the .asmx and .svc

Comment: If you figured out a way to do it please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use more modern technology, ditch the MS cascading dropdownlist and go with something like knockout.js and use your service of choice.